# Is changing an objects state/contents appropriate Iterator usage (php)

Tags: php, iterator

Consider an object used to store a collection of items, but that collection may vary depending on predefined contexts.

```
Class Container implements IteratorAggregate (
  protected $contexts; // list of associated contexts, example: array(0=>1,1=>3)
  protected $contents; // array
  public loadContents( $contextId ) { /* populates $this->contents*/ }
  public getContexts() { /* populates $this->contexts */ }
  ...
  public function getIterator() { return new ArrayIterator($this->contents); }
  public getContextIterator() { return new contextIterator($this); }
}
```

The iterator looks like:

```
Class contextIterator {
  protected $container;
  protected $contexts;
  protected $currentContext;

  public function __construct($container) {
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->contexts = $container->getContexts();
    $this->currentContext = 0;
  }

  public current() {
    $this->container->loadContents( $this->key() );
    return $this->contexts[ $this->key() ];
  }

  public function key() { return $this->currentContext; }
  public function next() { $this->currentContext++; }
  public function rewind() { $this->currentContext = 0; }
  public function valid() { return isset( $this->contexts[ $this->key() ] ); }
}
```

For the few cases where each context needs to be examined iteratively, I do the following:

```
$myContainer = new Container();
foreach( $myContainer->getContextIterator() as $key => $value ) {
  $myContainer->someMethod();
}
```

The above is nice and compact, but it feels dirty to me since I'm never actually using $key or $value. Is using the iterator overkill? Further, should an iterator ever change the state/contents of the object it is iterating?

Comment: `return $this->steps[ $this->key() ];` - where is `steps` declared? with full code it will be more easy to answer.

Comment: whoops, sorry about that. The property "steps" should of been "contexts". I edited my question. Do you still need more info?

Comment: I really don't get what your trying to accomplish here. Is this something that you are used to doing in other languages? I feel stupid for even having to ask this because I am sure there are more experienced programmers that are going to groan at my ignorance here.

Comment: umm so that foreach loop is kindah new to me, does the pointer to `$myContainer` change in each iteration?

Comment: @andho: $myContainer is an iterator object, so with each "loop" its "current" method is called returning a value for $key and $value. If the foreach is new to you, check out the [foreach doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). It is great for iterating over arrays. But, it can also be used to [iterate over an object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php).

Comment: @jbarreiros: But he is not using $key or $value inside the loop, $value will be the return value of 'current' method. $key will be the return value of 'key' method. but $myContainer will stay the same. So the loop is calling $myContainer->someMethod() over and over again which will have the same output.

Comment: Unless 'someMethod' uses the iterator methods 'current' to get the current object and calls 'someMethod' of that object maybe. Or even magic variable __call can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above is nice and compact, but it feels dirty to me since I'm never actually using $key or $value.

You have not shown the inners of `getContextIterator()` so it's hard to make concrete suggestions. Generally it's possible to create iterate-able objects in PHP by implementing the [`OuterIterator` interace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.outeriterator.php) or by just implementing the [`Iterator` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). Both interfaces are predefined and you then can use your object with `next()`, `foreach` etc.

I assume you've implemented something *like* `OuterIterator`. If you implement `OuterIterator` instead, you will get some speed benefit AFAIK.

> Is using the iterator overkill?

No, won't say so. Iterators are very good for collections as you said you have one. I just would change it into a SPL iterator though.

> Further, should an iterator ever change the state/contents of the object it is iterating?

Well actually each iterator does, at least for the internal pointer of the iteration. But I think that was not your concern, but might already lighten up.

So even for "more" changes inside the object you're iterating over, it's perfectly okay that it changes as long as it's clear what it does. Counter-Example: if you iterate over an array and it would shuffle elements each time the iteration goes one step ahead would not be useful.

But there are other cases where this is totally valid and useful. So decide on what's done, not with a general rule.

Comment: Thank you for the reply hakre. I actually forgot to include an important detail. The "Container" class already implements IteratorAggregate for looping over the collection items. The "ContextIterator" is an extra iterator when each context needs to be examined.

Comment: "... it's perfectly okay that it changes as long as it's clear what it does." -- I guess that is where I got hung up because I was not sure that it was clear.

Comment: @jbarreiros: Hmm, it looks like you've created an iterator to just return a specific instance then. That's somewhat bogus and makes things more complicated than it needs. For example: Why is `someMethod()` accessed through the iterator? It looks like a kind of iterateable decorator on the already iterateable collection class. Or is the collection class itself not iterateable and your iterator is a decorator for it? This all can be valid to do, however I would ideally keep things simple and fluid/decoupled. It still can be valid though. E.g. instantiate the iterator in the foreach.

Comment: "_you've created an iterator to just return a specific instance_" is correct. I created "ContextIterator" to return a specific instance of the Container class. -- The collection class is already iterateable to allow traversing the items in $contents, which is why "ContextIterator" is, as you call it, a _decorator_ on the collection class. -- Instantiating the iterator in the foreach does seem to make the code a little bit clearer.